# Magento 1.9.3 tinymce url('{{media url=" issue

Tags: magento-1.9, cms, tinymce

In Magento 1.9.3 it started to cut off media url inside cms editor:

```
<table style="background-image: url('{{media url="wysiwyg/image.jpg"}}');">
```

becomes this

```
<table style="background-image: url('{{media url=;">
```

Does anybody have any idea about workaround without using direct full url path?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<table style="background-image: url('{{media url=\"wysiwyg/image.jpg\"}}');">
```